# Plot 3D prisms using ggplot2 and plotly

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, 3d

I have a list `a` with three matrices and a vector `h` with three heights (any positive real number). These matrices form triangles, that is, the base of the prism. I want to add the information of vector `h` to construct prisms.

I've created a function to plot graphics in 2D (`pplot`). How can I plot the prisms as in the figure below?

Let `pplot` and a *toy problem* be an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
pplot <- function(polygon){
  polygon <- lapply(polygon, function(x) {colnames(x) <- NULL; x})
  vertex_number = nrow(polygon[[1]])
  g = ggplot2::ggplot()
  names(polygon) = 1:length(polygon)
  k <- plyr::ldply(polygon, function(x) data.frame(x))
  g <- ggplot2::ggplot(k, ggplot2::aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = .id)) + ggplot2::geom_polygon(colour = "black", fill = NA)
  return(g)
}

a <- list()
b1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

a[[1]] <- b1
a[[2]] <- b2
a[[3]] <- b3

h <- c(.3, .5, .1)
#pplot function example
pplot(a)
```

**Graphic desired**

[image: An example desired]

Where the coordinate `a = d`, `b = f`, `c = e` are vertices and all information is in `a`.

Observation 1: The data must a list.

Observation 2: I've created a post in portuguese, but nobody answered. Can I do this or it is cheating? (I'm new here)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165538/plotar-figuras-3d-para-dados-em-lista

Comment: I thought ggplot didn't do 3D. Can you point us to an example where that supposition is proven incorrect?

Comment: An example can be seen in: https://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-plots-with-ggplot2-and-plotly/

Comment: As I read that blog, it is plotly that is doing the 3D razzmatazz.

Comment: Yes, I modefied the title.

Comment: You need to explain what is desired. Perhaps the matrices are the coordinates of the bases of the polygonal pyramids and the "frequencies" are the heights? This would be a rather poorly designed graphic. This sort of graphic is typical of Excel and generally deprecated by the graphics experts who use R because the human perception of heights will not be accurate.

Comment: Yes "frequencies" isn´t the better word, I wanted to say height. The matrix is a triangular base and I have the  height to construct the prisms. Excel was not used anywhere in the process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128197/discussion-between-wagner-jorge-and-42).

Comment: I'm not really setup for chat, having only my cellphone at the moment. My comment about Excel was only to say that the plotly examples you referred to reminded me of the bad graphics that are criticized by Tufte and others. http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0002kk

Comment: I put an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the task correctly. Nevertheless here's a draft for a solution with the package `rgl`. In my opinion it's still the best 3D plotting framework for R, because it's much faster and scales better than the javascript APIs (plotly, rthreejs etc.).

```
#### load package rgl ####
library(rgl)

set.seed(1232)

#### construct test list with coordinate matrices ####
a <- list()
b1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
b3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

a[[1]] <- b1
a[[2]] <- b2
a[[3]] <- b3

#### define test height vector ####
h <- c(.3, .5, .1)

#### simple plot prism function ####
# a: list with coordinate matrices
# h: height vector
plotprism <- function(a, h){
  # general loop to plot every prism
  for(i in 1:length(h)){
    # transform matrizes to data.frames and add height column 
    # -> separation of top and bottom triangle
    top <- data.frame(a[[i]], h[i]) 
    bottom <- data.frame(a[[i]], 0) 
    # adjust colnames to axis names
    colnames(top) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
    colnames(bottom) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
    # plot triangles (as wireframes)
    triangles3d(bottom, front = "line", back = "line")
    triangles3d(top, front = "line", back = "line")
    # plot vertical lines to connect the triangles
    for(i in 0:2){
      segments3d(
        x = c(bottom$x[1+i], top$x[1+i]),
        y = c(bottom$y[1+i], top$y[1+i]),
        z = c(bottom$z[1+i], top$z[1+i])
      )
    }
  }
  #### add coordinate system ####
  axes3d()
}

#### call plot function for test data ####
plotprism(a, h)
```

The results:
[image]